# Hibernate Many to Many on many to

Tags: hibernate, annotations, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

I´m trying to map an existing database to Hibernate using annotations.
The problem is as follows.

'organization' and 'organization_roles' has a many to many relationship which is resolved in a 
table 'organization_has_roles' using the two primary keys as a composite primary key in the join table.

Next there is a 'users' table. Users can have a single role in multiple organizations. This is again resolved in a join table named 'users_has_organizations_and_role' which has a composite primary key of the 'user_id', 'organization_id' and 'organization_role_id' and a unique_index on the 'user_id' and 'organization_id'.

The 'users_has_organizations_and_role' references the 'organization_has_roles' composite primary key(organization_id, organization_role_id) and the users table (user_id)

I have not been able to find examples on this matter that worked.

Is it possible to map this. Which Annotations should I use and how?

I´m using Hibernate 4, although it might not matter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this approach is that you have an unmappable ORM mismatch: you have an entity in your database (`organization_has_roles`) which is translated as a relationship in OO. As this relationship is not an entity, and has no `@Id`, it cannot be referenced into yet another entity.

A solution is to map the database entity `organization_has_roles` into a JPA/Hibernate entity, with either a composite key, or with a synthetic key (whatever you prefer). You can then refer to this entity in your `User` model.

Comment: If I map organization_has_roles into a JPA/Hibernate entity with a composite key, I would also have to re-map the Organization and Organization_role JPA/Hibernate entities as well, right? As of now they are just mapped by a @ManyToMany with a JoinTable.

Comment: I feel a bit strange on OP's design. Normally it should be something Organization and Role, and they have many to many relationship. By changing the many-to-many to new entity OrganizationRole, you will see the thing as Organization-OrganizationRole  and Role-OrganizaitonRole being many-to-one

Comment: @Encory: That's right, you'd have to remap them, so they point to this new entity.

Comment: Organization and Role has a many to many relation. And the mappings for that was straight forward. The problem occurred when the user relation was introduced. Again in plain SQL JDBC no problems, but it has been some of a struggle to map it into Hibernate least to say. I think it is the fact that the join occurs via another join table. but I will give the new JPA/Hibernate entity suggestion a try. Although I had hoped there was some magical Annotation I had missed..

Comment: @AdrianShum , It certainly feels a bit strange, but it's logical, if you stop to think about it. The thing is: a Many to Many is just a relationship, be it at database level or OO level. If you need to reference this relationship somehow, then this relationship is not just a relationship, it's a thing (object, entity, you name it). At the database level, they are expressed the same way, but they are not expressed the same way in OO.

Comment: @Encory : No promises, but take a look also at the Hibernate Annotations extensions to JPA. There might be something for you there, but I still think that the single fact that you need a reference to this relationship makes it worth having a entity.

Comment: @jpkrohling In fact the part I feel strange is, instead of having "Role", OP called it "ComanyRole" (which name suggest it is a "role under a company").  I do agree on what you are saying about relationship and entity :)